# Why is my ajax not calling the controller?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Can someone help me to spot why my ajax is not calling the controller?  I’ve had success with similar ajax calls else where in my project but I can’t find anything wrong with my code.  Can you please help me with why this code fails to call the controller?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          var theParms = { selectedDate: "date", testing: "myTester" };
          $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/Error/TimeCheck",
                  data: theParms,
                  datatype: "html",
                  success: function (data) {                    
             }
         });
     });
   }); 
</script>
```

My controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{        
    public PartialViewResult Index()
    {            
        return PartialView(//some partial view);
    }

    public ActionResult TimeCheck( string selectedDate, string testing)
    {
        return Content("hello " + selectedDate);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your console say? Whats the status of the request?

Comment: this current code looks correct as it is, and works for me in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing JSON as the data, but HTML as the datatype.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
      var theParms = { selectedDate: "date", testing: "myTester" };
      $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
          $.ajax(
          {
              type: "GET",
              url: "/Error/TimeCheck",
              data: theParms,
              datatype: "json",
              success: function (data) {}
          });
     });
});
```

Comment: I tried doc.ready but still nothing.  Isn't   $(function () {}); the same as doc.ready?

Comment: Ah, apparently it is... have you tried changing the datatype to json?  I edited my answer to not include misinformation.

Comment: I'll try changing to json but what's the difference?  Would I have to change the return type in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try webinspector or firebug, mainly the network panel.

Comment: that inner () is not necessary in `}());`

Comment: I loaded it in Chrome and it worked.  Not with Firefox for some reason.  Thanks for helping guys!!!

Comment: For future reference wouldn't the shown function fire before the document loaded?  So the event binding wouldn't get hooked up properly?

Comment: @CloudKooper Make use of Firebug in Firefox and see if it is throwing some javascript errors. Firebug is an almost required tool for web development in Firefox.